# Aframe animation with javascript split id

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, webvr

i am developing an Aframe WebVR app, trying to write a function that will split a this.id into two parts and giving it to a variable then .setattribute

this is my code

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('remove-yellow', {
  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    console.log(this.id);
    var boxid = this.id.split("-")[0];
    console.log(boxid);
    boxid.setAttribute("animation__scale", "property: scale; from: 1 1 0.01; to: 0.001 0.001 0.001; dur: 150");
    });
  }
});
```

with var boxid, console will give uncaught TypeError: boxid.setAttribute is not a function.This is the box that I am trying to animate:

```
<a-box id="box1" position="0 2 -1.5" rotation="0 0 0" depth="0" width="1" height="1" color="#39dbd8" scale="0.001 0.001 0">
        <a-entity id="info" width="1" position="0 0 0.6" text="value: Hello people what is going on AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa; color:#000;"></a-entity>
        <a-box id="box1-close" class="clickable" remove-yellow id="box2" position="0.4 0.4 0.6" rotation="0 0 0" depth="0" width="0.15" height="0.15" color="#f00" scale="1 1 0">
        </a-box>
</a-box>
<a-box id="box1-show" class="clickable" add-yellow id="box3" position="0 2 -2" rotation="0 0 0" depth="0" width="0.5" height="0.5" color="#008000" scale="1 1 0"></a-box>
```

when box1-show is clicked, its id will be split"-", box1 will then receive the animation attribute. If I write:

```
box1.setAttribute("animation__scale", "property: scale; from: 1 1 0.01; to: 0.001 0.001 0.001; dur: 150");
```

it will work fine.But with var boxid, console will give uncaught TypeError: boxid.setAttribute is not a function.

I have tried the codes below from other solutions I found:

```
$(boxid).attr('animation__scale', 'property: scale; from: 1 1 0.1; to: 0.001 0.001 0.001; dur: 150');
```

the error will disappear but it will not animate.

I am thinking it might be a syntax error, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first the `id` is `box1-close`, then its redeclared as `box2`. Its best to use the `id` only for identification purposes, not to smuggle data :)

Normally You could use the global [data](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attribute:

```
<div data-id="box1"></div>
```

But considering it's best to fully utilize the a-frame component system,
You need to use the component's schema.

---

Should the component manipulate any other element on the scene, just do

```
<a-entity my-component="param: value">
```

and access it in the component by the reference `this.data.param`.

---

Moreover the id, split or not, is just a string, you can't set any attributes to it, hence the error. If you want to set an attribute to the element it represents, you can grab it using:
`document.querySelector("#" + value).setAttribute()`, or more properly with `document.getElementById(value).setAttribute()`.

You can check it out in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfksuhf9/11/).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that it wouldn't know that it wasn't an ID. Thanks!